# Compose lambda function in C++ using parameter pack

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates, function-composition

I'm new to C++ 14, I want to compose a variable length of lambda functions together to a single lambda, how should I do that? Below is my current work

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Ftype>
Ftype compose(const Ftype & fn) {
  return fn;
}

template<typename Ftype, typename... Other>
auto compose(Ftype fn, Other... other) {
  return [=](auto x){return other(fn(x))...;};
}        ➤ expression contains unexpanded parameter pack 'other'

int main(void) {
  auto add_func = [](const int x) { return x * 7; };
  auto sub_func = [](const int x) { return x + 1; };
  int res = compose(add_func, sub_func)(1);
  std::cout << "Result: " << res << "\n";
}
```

But I failed the compile, I guess I may use the lambda or variadic parameter somehow wrong.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your "recursive" case contains no call to `compose`, that should be a hint of where you've mixed things up ;)

```
return [=](auto x){ return compose(other...)(fn(x)); };
```

Comment: Thanks! But I just tried your way, it reports an error in main at the caller:
expression cannot be used as a function
   int res = compose(add_func, sub_func)(0);
                                          ^
How should I fix that?

Comment: @user7804610 I'm afraid that's an issue on your side, this single change [makes it work](https://wandbox.org/permlink/esxYzgNpMi02vD7Y) on mine... Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I made a minor mistake in my Makefile.